# Why print always reports an error does not support str and int connection?What is the usage of print?

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python so I have no idea what is going on.

```
import random

x=10
while x>0:
    print(x+'='+(random.randint(1,100)))
    x-=1
```

When I run the program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\black\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(x+'='+(random.randint(1,100)))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: you can use f-string `print(f'{x} = {random.randint(1,100)}')`

Comment: Or simply `print(x,'=',random.randint(1,100))` - items will be space-separated.  Actually you could write `print(x, '=', random.randint(1,100))` *not* because the extra whitespace here makes any difference to the output, but just because it is more readable with the spaces.

Comment: This will help you learn about f-strings, which can solve your issue: (https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` is integer, but you are trying to concatenate it with string (equal sign).

You need to convert both x and the random value after equal sign to string:

```
import random

x=10
while x>0:
    print(str(x)+'='+str(random.randint(1,100)))
    x-=1
```